# Is there any documentation on the Pinnacle PCTV API?

Tags: c#, api, actionscript, video, television

I need to develop is an application that shows the TV signal along with information on the channel being displayed.  My only need is to communicate the app with the card to change channels and get the video.

[image: it should look like this]

So, I need to operate a Pinnacle PCTV (-like) card from Actionscript OR C#.  Actionscript is preferred, but C# is being considered in case Actionscript cannot interface with the card.

I've been searching on Google but I haven't found any relevant resources.

Is there any API documentation available online?

Comment: I also wondered if a ADS Tech DVDExpress would also allow creating a custom interface - but I can't find any API documentation - it is possible that Pinnacle doesn't provide a API -> they probably want you to use their software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally used Microsoft's DirectShow interface for accessing the TV capture board functionality with C#.